# CSS Animation FadeIn/Out Issue

Tags: html, css, animation

I seem to be getting an issue with my CSS animation where when I close the Dropdown the background disappears straight away whilst the rest fades away and it makes the dropdown look strange, I have tried everything I can find on CSS animation with no luck so I thought I'd reach out to see if anyone knew.

index.html

```
<li class="menu-item-3 dropdown">
    <a>Info for volunteers</a>
    <ul class="child">
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $root; ?>volunteers/your-roles/">
                <div class="bold">Your roles</div>
                <div class="sub">Your current roles and support</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $root; ?>volunteers/news/">
                <div class="bold">News</div>
                <div class="sub">News for members</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $root; ?>volunteers/information/">
                <div class="bold">Information</div>
                <div class="sub">Useful downloads and pages</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

style.css

```
.header .nav_container .desktop ul li ul.child {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc( 100% + 30px );
    z-index: 900;
    background-color: #fff;
    right: -10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 32px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.3);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    animation: fadeout 0.3s;
}
.header .nav_container .desktop ul li ul.child.open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    animation: fadein 0.3s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0;margin-top: 40px; }
    to   { opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px; }
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px; }
    to   { opacity: 0;margin-top: 40px; }
}
```

Any ideas would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello the code you posted seems to be incomplete and i would guess you are using some other CSS libraries, nevertheless form what i understand you want to achieve the below.

EDIT:
visibility:hidden attribute should be removed from the .header .nav_container .desktop ul li ul.child selector

```
.header .nav_container .desktop ul li ul.child {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc( 100% + 30px );
    z-index: 900;
    background-color: #fff;
    right: -10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 32px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 0 rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.3);
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeout 0.3s;
}
.header .nav_container .desktop ul li ul.child.open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    animation: fadein 0.3s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0;margin-top: 40px; }
    to   { opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px; }
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px; }
    to   { opacity: 0;margin-top: 40px; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering I tried to get only the relevant code as I have some serious tidying to do. I swapped the keyframes over but this made no difference the background is still disappearing. Feel free to take a look at the site. It's the main menu dropdowns https://isleofwightscouts.scoutweb.services/

Comment: I found your problem, YOu need to remove the visibility:hidden attribute on the following slector ".header .nav_container .desktop ul li ul.child". It is what is causing the wonky behaviour. You can also go back to your previous code on the keyframes.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it.